# Oracle APEX for "Airport" database

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm making a database of an imaginary Airport that has a simplified physical model of 10 tables. The final part is to make some kind of web-based GUI for users, I have three general types of them: airport manager, airline representative and user/visitor of the airport website.

Currently I'm planning to build the interface with Oracle APEX and my concerns are about if it suites the target. I need several views for every type of user. So I need flight table for visitors and different control panels for airport manager and airline representative (manager has more power :), representative can only change flight information on rows related to HIS company etc.). Can I do it with APEX and will I be able to implement PL/SQL triggers and procedures myself?

I'm asking because APEX installation is a time-consuming task and I don't want it to be a time-wasting one...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apex is included with 10g and 11g Express Editions so installation shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Apex is probably easier than any other tool to build such an application, and it has all the flexibility you could possibly need to handle these requirements.  You can use [Authorisation Schemes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e11838/sec.htm#BABEDFGB) to give each type of user access to different pages, and to different information and functionality within pages.

You may want to start by going through the [2-day developer's guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13367/toc.htm).